# Compiling Qt 4.8.x for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012

What steps should I take to compile Qt (version 4.8.x) for Visual Studio 2012?

I already carefully followed the instructions in the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601950/how-to-build-qt-for-visual-studio-2010) (which is for VS 2010), but WebKit module failed to compile (I'm not sure if the error message was logged anywhere during compilation).

I also saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863466/how-to-set-visual-studio-2012-rc-compiler-for-qt-instead-of-mingw) which asks the same, but for VS 2012 RC (which is why I thought this wouldn't be a duplicate question). Furthermore, the answerer says he has compiled Qt for VS 2011 Beta, so there's a chance it may not work for VS 2012 (RTM). The compilation takes a *lot* of time, which is why I have not tried it yet.

At least one problem I realized is that there's no `win32-msvc2012` directory in `Qt\mkspecs`. Should I just create that directory and copy the files from `win32-msvc2010`, possibly with some modifications?

Another sub-question is whether I should make some modifications to Qt sources before starting compilation.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Qt 4.8.3 with Visual Studio 2012 x64 (should also work with 4.8.2)

1. Install [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/)
2. Download Qt 4.8.3 source code from http://qt-project.org/downloads
3. Go to `mkspecs\win32-msvc2010`. Open `qmake.conf` and change:

   ```
   QMAKE_COMPILER_DEFINES  += _MSC_VER=1600 WIN32
   ```

   to:

   ```
   QMAKE_COMPILER_DEFINES  += _MSC_VER=1700 WIN32
   ```
4. Replace `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.3-x64\src\3rdparty\webkit\Source\JavaScriptCore\wtf\HashSet.h` by [this `HashSet.h`](https://bitbucket.org/Vertexwahn/bluego/src/56dbe84212222ec6954d8d327a5e443106bcc447/deploy/BlueGo0.0.4/qt4.8.3vs2012patch/HashSet.h?at=default).
5. Start "VS2012 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt"
6. Switch to Qt 4.8.3 source directory (the directory that contains `configure.exe`)
7. Run:

   ```
   configure -mp -opensource -nomake demos -nomake examples -platform win32-msvc2010
   ```
8. Followed by:

   ```
   nmake
   ```

I programmed a tool called BlueGo which automatically downloads Qt 4.8.3 and builds it with VS2012 x64: http://bluego.vertexwahn.de (also works with VS2010 x64) (it just does what I described above automatically)

Comment: Strawberry Perl? Is that if I want to use your tool?

Comment: You have to install Strawberry Perl (http://strawberryperl.com/) if you want to use my tool to build qt (because it is needed to build qt) - the new version of my tool which will be released the next days will check before the build button is hit if Perl is installed.

Comment: A couple of quick notes: 1) thank you for this **awesome** answer, saving me a lot of time 2) you can use ActiveState Perl instead of Strawberry Perl - either works.

Comment: @Vertexwahn For clarification, is Strawberry Perl absolutely necessary to build Qt with VS2012 or can steps 2-8 be done without it? Additionally, I shouldn't need the hash set because I'm using -no-webkit?

Comment: Additionally, for me qt creator said the binaries were incompatible between x86 and x64 when specifying qt version?

Comment: @rem45acp The perl command needs to be available - if you do not have a perl installation steps 2-8 will fail. I am not sure if hash set needs to be fixed when building with –no-webkit. I do not use the qt creator – I use CMake, VS2010/12 together with Qt – so I can also not help you with your Qt creator issue

Comment: It worked for me, even though I don't have a Perl package installed on my system. Just needed to patch the file.

Comment: We still have to apply HashSet.h patch even with Qt 4.8.6 and VS2012

Comment: @Androidcus No. You have to apply several patched before you can build Qt 4.8.3 using VS2013. Use Qt 5.6 alpha if this is possible for you.

Answer (score 22):

Qt 4.8.4 needs less tweaking than described by Vertexwahn above.

- The HashSet still has to be fixed (see [fix of Vertexwahn](https://bitbucket.org/Vertexwahn/bluego/src/56dbe84212222ec6954d8d327a5e443106bcc447/deploy/BlueGo0.0.4/qt4.8.3vs2012patch/HashSet.h?at=default)) after Qt has been extracted from archive.
- Platform win32-msvc2012 is supported out-of-the-box though (also works for 64bit in the 64bit environment, don't ask why they name it Win32).

So simply replace the HashSet.h and compile.

Comment: `Win32` is used as an OS API platform: the Win32 API is available on all Windows desktops (x86, x64, and previously 64-bit Itanium). 64-bit doesn't need a different toplevel configuration, so to keep things compatible they kept the name.

Answer (score 6):

Just creating a win32-msvc2012 directory with the changes below didn't work for me, there is more editing necessary. What exactly is necessary is described in the thread you already linked.

What I did, I went to win32-msvc2010.

There, open qmake.conf and change

QMAKE_COMPILER_DEFINES  += _MSC_VER=1600 WIN32

to

QMAKE_COMPILER_DEFINES  += _MSC_VER=1700 WIN32

Then I could configure using win32-msvc2010.

Also, I used these changes: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/17771 (alzi's Version)

Comment: When you say "Then I could configure using win32-msvc2010" do you mean win32-msvc2012? When I did this in a x64 command prompt qt creator would not compile due to the difference in architecture and compilers.