# Compiling Qt 4.8.x for Visual Studio 2012 (x86)

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012

I already have successfuly compiled Qt 4.8.3 for visual studio 2012 (x64) using the guideline in question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113400/compiling-qt-4-8-x-for-visual-studio-2012/13085842#13085842) but the problem is that, this solution only works for 64-bit compilation, Although compiling 32-bit (x86) completes without an error, webkit keeps crashing (access violation), for example, qt designer would crash immediately on startup, anybody got any luck? :(

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Qt 4.8.4 got msvc2012 support officially. Maybe you ask Digia or qt-project for your issue. Just a clue.

https://www.qt.io/blog/2012/11/29/qt-4-8-4-released

https://web.archive.org/web/20121203035216/http://qt.digia.com/Release-Notes/Release-Notes-Qt-484/

Comment: WebKit does not work with msvc2012 as stated at http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/11/29/qt-4-8-4-released/

Comment: Thank you :) It's so unfortunate, although they say binaries from VS2010 should work fine, I dag into the patched "HashSet.h" and found nothing strange, seems it takes a while to be fixed, BTW, is it compiler bug with VS2012?

Comment: I built qt4.8.4 for x86 with VS2012 (with patched HashSet.h): same problem here designer.exe is not working - but linguist.exe - not sure if designer.exe depends on webkit