# linker error when building an applicatio which uses QT

Tags: c++, qt, linker, x86, 64-bit

I just compiled qt as explained here:

[Compiling Qt 4.8.x for Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113400/compiling-qt-4-8-x-for-visual-studio-2012)

But when I am compiling my code which was written by somebody else, I am getting this rror:

```
Error   74  error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'   projectDir\QtCored4.lib(QtCored4.dll)
```

What is the problem and how can  fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to build 32bit software with 64bit libraries?

Comment: @cmannett85 not really! I am just trying to build my application. It seems that I compiled QT for 64 bit system and my application is targeted for 32 bit